# Lists Allowing for Pushing, Popping & Switching Values

Tags: list, caching, d

Is there a way in D to have a list that allows you to shift 
around values? I'm creating a cache and I would like to keep a 
log of when an item was last accessed so when the cache shrinks 
or is about to overflow I can delete the items that haven't been 
accessed in a while.

I would like to be able to push to the back and pop from the 
front. Do note that I would like to pop from the front, and not 
from the back, as I want the oldest items to be popped out.

I would like the be able to search if the item is actually in the 
list. If no such functionality exists yet I could alternatively 
implement it myself; it's not crucial.

I would like to be able to switch items around. This allows me 
when an item already in the list is accessed, I can put it back 
at the back, where the most recent items reside.

Does such a feature exist already in D, is there perhaps a better 
approach about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such D package that I know of. Ideally it should behave like the [JCache](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=107), but I am afraid that would be too much to ask. :) JCache is going to be an amazing addition to the already excellent Java API.

D community would certainly benefit from something like that.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use either the SList (single linked list) or a double linked list as the base for your cache wrapper.

When the entry is accessed you remove it from the linked list and add it to the beginning.
This solution doesn't need so much computational overhead.

Comment: I'm already going with a chain based approach atm; do you think your approach will be faster?

Comment: i honestly don't know, if you need speed you could write also your own linked list implementation (and benchmark it after that), do this only if its worth the dev/debugging time/cost

Answer (score 2):

I find that many people with CS background have a common wrong belief that one must use a clever data structure for the use cases they consider "non-trivial". I believe this comes from all the time that is usually spent lecturing about asymptotic operations complexity.

The mere fact is that 95% of the time (or more) an array is the data structure you must use. While it is hard to believe from mathematical purist point of view, it is actually so on practice.

Consider an example from one of the talks by Bjarne Stroustroup http://bulldozer00.com/2012/02/09/vectors-and-lists/

In short, he provides measurements for the task that any CS student will tell you is just made for the linked list data structure and vector is the last thing you should consider. On practice, it turns out to be quite the opposite - vector-based implementation by far beats the list-based one (and for good reasons).

Another authority, Alexander Stepanov (the designer and first implementer of the C++'s STL) teaches on his courses the same. To loosely quote him, that's what he tells the students: "Always use vector when you need a container. There's a gazillion of data structures out there, but those are not for you. You - you always use vector."

Obviously, he exaggerates, but the point is clear - by far, most of the time, the preferred data structure is vector.

So back to the question. The minute you've said "I would like the be able to search if the item is actually in the list." you should be settled with an array. If at some point later you'll suspect that this choice is a real bottle-neck, you should very carefully measure it and use something else making sure it does work faster (usually, it won't be that trivial).

From the implementation side, D has popFront method which works with arrays and concatenation with ~ operator. You can use random access, swap elements around, use canFind and pretty much everything from std.algorithm with arrays. Also, arrays have length property, so you can handle its growth.

The caveat one can point in this approach is that it implicitly comes with a memory allocation strategy which may seem wasteful. But practically, it's a good default and you should really measure the metric you're worried about (performance and/or memory footprint) before switching to something else.

Comment: Surely though a single list is faster than 2 vectors. Vectors would require me to split access times and data in a different vectors, while a list would just allow me to start looking at the front of the list and move on to items less likely to be searched for on the back of the list, as they haven't been used for a while.

Comment: As far as I can see, you can use a single vector for the task (using popFront and concatenation), I don't see why you'll need 2 vectors. And while you're worried about inconsistent memory access pattern, you should know that the reason lists are generally slow is exactly because it uses random memory access pattern by design.

Comment: I'm thinking of a chain based approach meaning items which get requested a lot will get quicker lookup times (as they're up front) and sorting them is as simple as unchaining and rechaining data requiring no allocation. I'm still not sure how a vector can beat that...

Comment: Maybe we're talking about different things? I consider a case when you need a container with the following operations: popping front element, appending to the end, swapping of elements and linear search. My point is that in this list linear search is the most expensive operation and vector performs much better than a list on it. So, most of the time it beats it overall. That may not be your case depending on the usage pattern (e.g. you almost don't use linear search and perform popping and appending a lot), but chances are good that it actually is. The only way to be sure is measurement.